# Limitar el tamaño de imagen al subirla con PHP

Tags: imagen, archivo, upload

resulta que quiero controlar el peso de la imágenes cuando un usuario intenta subirla a mi sitio web, pero resulta que **PHP** lo tiene con *byte* y la verdad es que no entiendo ese calculo.
Yo quiero que si una imagen pese 2MB marque un error al usuario diciéndole que esta muy pesada la imagen y que pruebe con una menos pesada.

Lo quiero hacer de esta forma para que la pagina se mantenga muy rápida ya que si no hay un control del peso de la imagen yo pienso que eso es una vulnerabilidad.

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te puse un ejemplo, con 2mb en bytes. Espero que te sea útil.

```
$maxSize = 2097152 ; // 2 MB
$image = $_FILES["imagen"];

if($image["size"] < $maxsize) {
echo "la img pesa menos de 2mb, todo bien";
}else {
echo "la img pesa más de 2mb";
}
```